# problema al enviar comentarios se repiten

Tags: php, jquery

estoy creando un sistema de comentarios en php y jquery todo marcha bien hasta que intento enviar un segundo comentario tambien me manda el anterior y asi susesivamente, ojala y puedan encontrar mi error aqui esta mi codigo

coment.php

```
<div id="push-<?php echo$registro['id'];?>"></div><!--show coments here-->
    <div id="texto" style="padding:0px;">

     <!-- id unico para el formulario ya que hay varios formularios-->
    <form action="comentarios.php"  method="post" class="formu" id="formu-<?php echo$registro['id'];?>">


    <div class="input-group  mb-2 col-12" style=" margin: 0 auto;">

        <img src="imagenes/<?php echo$_SESSION['avatar'];?>" >
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un comentario..." name="comentario" id="comentario" >
        <input type="hidden" style="display: none;" name="id_public" id="id_public" value="<?php echo$registro['id'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" style="display: none;" name="id_owner" id="id_owner" value="<?php echo$registro['id_user'];?>">


      <div class="input-group-append" >
       <button type="submit"  class="btn-outline-info consulta" id="<?php echo$registro['id'];?>">
       <img src="img/plane.png" width="20px" height="20px"  >
       </button>

      </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </form>
    </div>
```

coments.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

   $(".consulta").click(function(){

    var id = this.id;//get id value
    var owner= $("#id_owner").val();
    var comentario= $("#comentario").val();
    var push= $("#push-"+id);

  $("#formu-"+id).submit(function(){

      $.ajax({

       url:"comentarios.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:$("#formu-"+id).serialize(),
       dataType:'json',

       success:function(datas){
        console.log(datas);

        push.append("<div id='post_coments_container'><img id='post_coments_img' src='imagenes/"+datas["avatar"]+"' >"+"<div id='post_coments'>"+ "<a href='#'> "+datas["usuario"]+" "+datas["apellido"]+ "</a>"+"<span>"+moment(fecha).format('LT')+"</span>"+"<div id='post_coments_messages'>"+datas["comentario"]+ "</div>"+"</div>" +"</div>");
        $("#comentario").val("");
    },
    error:function(datas){
      console.log(datas)
    }


  });

     return false;

    });



    });



});
```

no inclui el ajax por que en realidad funciona bien lo unico que no se que estoy haciendo mal en el archivo js ,alguna idea de mi error lo he intentado de varias forma y nada

Comment: ¿Estás limpiando el formulario una vez enviado cada comentario?

Answer (score -2):

coment.php

```
<div id="push-<?php echo$registro['id'];?>"></div><!--show coments here-->
<div id="texto" style="padding:0px;">
    <!-- id unico para el formulario ya que hay varios formularios-->
    <form action="comentarios.php"  method="post" class="formu" id="formu-<?php echo$registro['id'];?>">
        <div class="input-group  mb-2 col-12" style=" margin: 0 auto;">
            <img src="imagenes/<?php echo$_SESSION['avatar'];?>" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un comentario..." name="comentario" id="comentario" >
            <input type="hidden" style="display: none;" name="id_public" id="id_public" value="<?php echo$registro['id'];?>">
            <input type="hidden" style="display: none;" name="id_owner" id="id_owner" value="<?php echo$registro['id_user'];?>">
            <div class="input-group-append" >
                <button type="button"  class="btn-outline-info consulta" id="<?php echo$registro['id'];?>">
                    <img src="img/plane.png" width="20px" height="20px"  >
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

coments.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".consulta").click(function() {
        var id = this.id; //get id value
        var owner = $("#id_owner").val();
        var comentario = $("#comentario").val();
        var push = $("#push-" + id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "comentarios.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#formu-" + id).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(datas) {
                console.log(datas);
                push.append("<div id='post_coments_container'><img id='post_coments_img' src='imagenes/" + datas["avatar"] + "' >" + "<div id='post_coments'>" + "<a href='#'> " + datas["usuario"] + " " + datas["apellido"] + "</a>" + "<span>" + moment(fecha).format('LT') + "</span>" + "<div id='post_coments_messages'>" + datas["comentario"] + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>");
                $("#comentario").val("");
            },
            error: function(datas) {
                console.log(datas)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Cuál fue la solución aplicada? Una respuesta así no tiene sentido, recuerda que este sitio está pensado para servir a otros usuarios que tengan problemas similares. Deberías explicar brevemente dónde detectas el problema y por qué aportas ese código como solución.

Comment: El problema es que los datos se repiten cuando haces el submit, se enviaran los datas del formulario y luego hace el $.ajax la misma Acción, y por eso es que tiene el problema de los datos repetidos, La solución que yo propongo es no activar el submit del formulario, y solo usar el $.ajax para enivar los datos, solo tienes que cambiar el tipo de **button** de **submit** a **button**, ejm: <button type="button"> y en el js remplasar el evento **submit** por evento **click** del button.

Comment: hey! interesante solucion pero si desactivo el submit que pasara con los inputs que se envian a la otra pagina como por ejemplo inputs de tipo hiddense mandarian igual?